# Substitute some 1s with 0s in random list

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing, binary

How is it better to substitute list of random combination of 1 and 0 (binary image) so that only first (or central) instance of 1 left in each group.

`list = {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0}` should be `{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0}`

There should be a kind of `Erosion` but keeping `1`s. I'm thinking about replacement rule.

Comment: `list//. {a___, 1, 1, Shortest[b___]} :> {a, 1, 0, b}`

Comment: `Cases[Prepend[Differences[list], First[list]], x_ :> Boole[x == 1]]
`

Comment: @LouisB, you could use `Ramp` to get a really cool solution.

Comment: @garej  Thanks for the `Ramp` suggestion.  It's fast, too.  I used it an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated to include suggestions from comments**

My original idea, using [`BitAnd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BitAnd), switching $0\leftrightarrow1$, and multiplying. This idea uses 3 vectorized binary operations:

```
erode1[list_] := Times[
    list,
    Subtract[
        1,
        BitAnd[list, PadRight[list, Length@list, 0, 1]]
    ]
]
```

Here is @Shadowray's improvement, which uses 2 vectorized binary operations. In addition, [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad) is slightly faster than [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight):

```
erode2[list_] := Times[
    list,
    BitXor[list, ArrayPad[list, {1, -1}]]
]
```

Finally, here is an approach inspired by @garej and @LouisB, which uses 1 vectorized binary operation and 1 vectorized unary operation:

```
erode3[list_] := Ramp @ Subtract[
    list,
    ArrayPad[list, {1, -1}]
]
```

Here is a comparison of there timings:

```
data = RandomInteger[1, 10^7];

r1 = erode1[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = erode2[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r3 = erode3[data]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.101, Null}
>
> {0.082, Null}
>
> {0.078, Null}
>
> True

*vectorized unary vs binary operators*

@io_tuta ask about vectorized unary vs binary operators. This answer [(3496)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3500/45431) provides a very nice description of vectorized (i.e. packed array) operations. As for the particular difference between unary and binary operators, I expect that unary operators ought to be faster than binary operators. Here is an example demonstrating this:

```
d1 = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
d2 = RandomReal[1, 10^7];

d1+d2; //RepeatedTiming
UnitStep[d1]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.024, Null}
>
> {0.019, Null}

The unary [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep) operation is significantly faster than the binary [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) operation

Comment: `BitXor` is a bit faster: `erode[list_]:=BitXor[ArrayPad[list,{1,-1}], list]*list`

Comment: @Shadowray Thanks, I included your suggestion.

Comment: @CarlWoll, congratulations with 10k )) Can you explain about vectorized unary vs ectoized binary operations?

Answer (score 8):

The following function is based on the [`Ramp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ramp.html) and [`Differences`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences.html) functions, as suggested in a comment by @garej .  Its speed and low memory are surprising.

```
rampDiff[list_] := Ramp@Prepend[Differences[list], First[list]]
```

It was tested against the following functions from previous answers and comments:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

erode1[list_] := 
 Times[list, 
  Subtract[1, BitAnd[list, PadRight[list, Length@list, 0, 1]]]]

erode2[list_] := BitXor[ArrayPad[list, {1, -1}], list]*list

fcn = Function[{list}, 
   Replace[Split[list], 
     l : {1, __} :> {1, ConstantArray[0, Length@l - 1]}, 1] // 
    Flatten];

bruteForce[list_] := 
  Join[{list[[1]]}, 
   Table[If[list[[i - 1]] == list[[i]] == 1, 0, list[[i]]], {i, 2, 
     Length[list]}]];

rep[a_] := a
rep[{1, a___}] := {1, {a} - 1}
repSplit[list_] := rep /@ Split@list // Flatten

shortest[list_] := (list //. {a___, 1, 1, Shortest[b___]} :> {a, 1, 0,
      b})

caseDiff[list_] := 
 Cases[Prepend[Differences[list], First[list]], x_ :> Boole[x == 1]]
```

The first test was to see that all of the functions give the same results.

```
functions = { shortest, bruteForce,  repSplit, fcn, caseDiff, erode2, 
   erode1, rampDiff};
data = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, 10^4];

results = Through[functions[data]];
1 == Length@Union@results

(*   True   *)
```

The execution time and memory usage tests were conducted as follows.

```
Through[(Composition[AbsoluteTiming, MaxMemoryUsed, #] & /@ 
     functions)[data]];
μsecs = Round[Transpose[{1000000, 1} Transpose[%]], 1];
Grid[Prepend[μsecs, {"μ-secs", "Bytes"}], 
 Alignment -> {Right, Baseline}]

   (* μ-secs      Bytes
      600599     321656
        7894     169720
        6166     813704
        4284     848216
        5789    1291216
        2737     720384
         344     320856
         230     160408   *)
```

In this test the `rampDiff` function edged out `erode1` in speed and `bruteForce` in low memory usage.  Thanks to @garej for suggesting it.

Comment: The difference between your testing and mine is that your `data` is not packed, while my `data` was packed. If you were to repeat your tests with packed data, you would find that your solution is slower than both `erode1` and `erode2`.

Answer (score 6):

First [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) the list into runs of zeros and ones:

```
split = Split[list]
```

> ```
> {{0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1}, {0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0}}
> ```

Then process the lists of ones with length greater than one.  One method is with a replacement rule, though a functional approach *might* be a bit faster:

```
Replace[split, l : {1, ___} :> {1, ConstantArray[0, Length@l - 1]}, 1]
```

> ```
> {{0}, {1, {0}}, {0, 0}, {1}, {0}, {1, {0, 0}}, {0}}
> ```

and finally [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) to get the desired output:

```
Flatten @ %
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

---

Putting it all together:

```
fcn = Function[{list},
 Replace[Split[list],
   l : {1, __} :> {1, ConstantArray[0, Length@l - 1]},
   1]
  // Flatten
 ]

fcn @ list
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

---

Note:  We could have used `Sequence@@ConstantArray[...]` in the second step, but I didn't bother since we were planning to flatten the list anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
rep[a_] := a
rep[{1, a___}] := {1, {a} - 1}

rep /@ Split@list // Flatten
```

> {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using `Table` that is mid-way in terms of speed:

```
bruteForce[list_] := Join[{list[[1]]}, Table[If[list[[i - 1]] == list[[i]] == 1, 0, list[[i]]], {i, 2, 
     Length[list]}]];


data = RandomInteger[1, 10^6];
r1 = erode[data]; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = fcn[data]; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
r3 = bruteForce[data]; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
r1 === r3
```

> {0.0101832, 16000656}
>
> {0.395556, 84964056}
>
> {0.0529076, 16000760}
>
> True
>
> True