# Set a repeating number to 0 within a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

Apologies for the simple nature but can't quite grasp a nice way of doing this.

take a list ~ `m0 = Table[RandomInteger[], 20]`

`{1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1}`

I want to send any `1` followed by a `1` to `0` such that the example would go to:

`{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1}`

I'm sure there is a quick and elegant way of doing this but it escapes me without a clunky method using `ReplaceRepeated[]`.

Thanks if anyone has a go.

Edit*

Just for reference of timing:

```
In[27]:= m0
ReplaceRepeated[m0,{s___,1,1,e___} :>  {s,0,1,e}]//AbsoluteTiming
Out[27]= {1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1}
Out[28]= {0.0000940839,{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1}}
```

Edit*

Thanks for all the Interesting attempts! Here is the timings when scaled to a bigger list

```
In[205]:= m0//Length
ReplaceRepeated[m0,{s___,1,1,e___} :>  {s,0,1,e}];//RepeatedTiming
Flatten[Split[m0]/.{x__,1}:>{0{x},1}];//RepeatedTiming
Differences[Append[m0,0]]/.{-1->1,1->0};//RepeatedTiming
First/@(Partition[Append[m0,0],2,1]/.{1,1}->{0,0});//RepeatedTiming
Append[BitShiftRight@@@Partition[m0,2,1],Last@m0];//RepeatedTiming

Out[205]= 500
Out[206]= {0.0020,Null}
Out[207]= {0.0004,Null} 
Out[208]= {0.000097,Null}
Out[209]= {0.00036,Null}
Out[210]= {0.00020,Null}
```

Comment: Related: [(148134)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148134/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
f1 = Flatten[Split[#] /. {x__, 1} :> {0{x} , 1}]&;
f1 @ m0
```

> {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}

Also

```
f2 = Differences[Append[#, 0]] /. {-1 -> 1, 1 -> 0}&;
f2 @ m0
```

> {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}

**Update:** Inspired by Mr.Wizard's post, an alternative way to use `Differences`:

```
f3 = 1 - UnitStep @ Differences @ Append[#, 0]&
f3 @ m0
```

> {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}

```
f4 = 1 - UnitStep @ Subtract[Rest @ Append[#, 0] , #]&
f4 @ m0
```

> {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}

**Timings:**

```
f5 = First /@ (Partition[Append[#, 0], 2, 1] /. {1, 1} -> {0, 0}) &; (* Fred Simons *)
f6 = Append[BitShiftRight @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1], Last @ #] &; (* march *) 
f7 = Ramp @ ListCorrelate[{1, -1}, #, 1, 0] &; (* Mr. Wizard *)
f8 = Ramp @ Differences[-Append[#, 0]] &; (* Mr. Wizard *)
f9 = FixedPoint[SequenceReplace[{1, 1} -> Sequence[0, 1]], #] &; (* Pillsy*)
f10 = Append[BitShiftRight[Most[#], Rest[#]], Last[#]] &; (*march*)

SeedRandom[1]
m0 = RandomInteger[1, 5*^5];
functions = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10};
labels = {"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8", "f9", "f10"};
{timings, results} = ConstantArray[1, {2, 10}];

Table[timings[[i]] = First[RepeatedTiming[results[[i]] = functions[[i]][m0];]], {i, 10}];

Grid[Prepend[SortBy[Transpose[{labels, functions, timings}], Last],
  {"function", SpanFromLeft, "timing"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

All except `f9` produce the same result:

```
Equal @@ results
```

> False

```
 Equal @@ results[[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10}]]
```

> True

Comment: Nice work.  I didn't expect `Subtract` to be faster than `Differences`; that didn't use to be the case I believe.

Comment: "Your approach took too long to benchmark," is always a bad sign.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,  there was a recent post where timing comparisons of several functions  were quite different  in v9 vs v11 (can't find the link now).

Comment: @Pillsy, I have had quite a few of those:)

Comment: It's worth adding the version of mine that @lasenH made faster, if you want!

Comment: @march, updated the timings table.

Answer (score 6):

Another one, not as nice as those of @kglr:

```
First /@ (Partition[Append[m0, 0], 2,1] /. {1,1}->{0,0})

(* {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work.

```
Append[BitShiftRight @@@ Partition[m0, 2, 1], Last@m0]
```

Edit: a faster version based on a comment by [lasenH](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51484/lasen-h):

```
Append[BitShiftRight[Most[m0], Rest[m0]], Last[m0]]
```

Comment: `Append[BitShiftRight[Most[m0], Rest[m0]], Last[m0]]` is an order of magnitude faster

Comment: @lasenH. Thanks for that. That's great! I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 6):

There's a slightly clunky way to do it with the new [`SequenceReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html) function:

```
SequenceReplace[m0, 
 seq : {1 .., 1} :> Apply[Sequence, PadLeft[{1}, Length[seq]]]]
(* {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1} *)
```

This one isn't going to run any races either (it's twice as slow as @kglr's `f5` above, on my machine) but at least it's not too slow to benchmark:

```
f9 = FixedPoint[SequenceReplace[{1, 1} -> Sequence[0, 1]], #1] &;
f9[m0] 
(* {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: (+1) i tried almost everything else with `SequenceReplace`:)

Answer (score 6):

Since it appears you are interested in performance I think you'll want to avoid replacements like `/. {-1 -> 1, 1 -> 0}` and use fast numeric functions instead.

Please add these to your performance test:

```
Ramp @ ListCorrelate[{1, -1}, m0, 1, 0]

Ramp @ Differences[-Append[m0, 0]]      (* based on kglr's answer *)
```

Please also use a larger set like `m0 = RandomInteger[1, 5*^5]` so differences are not lost in noise.

If you are using a version before 11.0 when [`Ramp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ramp.html) was introduced you can use:

```
Ramp = # * UnitStep@# &;
```

Comment: Thanks, Nice! Interesting method but what is the variable `big`? Apologies if I've missed something.

Comment: @AwkwardPanda sorry, mistake from my own testing.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Flatten @ SequenceSplit[list, x : {1 ..} :> {Table[0, Length[x] - 1], 1}]
```

{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
patts = {s : {1 ..} :> PadLeft[{1}, Length[s]], s : {0 ..} :> s};

Flatten[Riffle @@ Map[SequenceCases[list, #] &, patts]]

(*{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}*)
```